# JScience Amount with BigDecimal instead of double

Tags: java, jscience

So, I'm using JScience to do some calculations with the Amount class.

The problem is, I'm handling money, among other things, and as far as I can see, Amount uses double as its internal representation. Obviously, there is a problem with double not being as precise.

There is Measure, which allows me to chose between BigDecimal, double etc. but they don't have arithmetic operations between them.

Is there a class in the library that I'm missing, or would I have to roll out my own?